# Node - Express converting array to "Object" Map

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, vue.js

I created a web application using node express for the backend and vue for the front end. 
Right now I'm posting an object to express, using jquery (i know its going to be switched later), that contains an array. When the array hits the express router it converts the array in the object to an map. If i print the object in the console it appears to still be an array, but when express gets it, its an map. Anyone know what is causing this issue, or ideas on how to resolve this?

index.vue

```
test(){
    // testing why express is mapping maps 
    const body = {
        user_id:0,
        user_name:'',
        user_email:'',
        user_projects:[{test:'test'}]
    }
    console.log(body)
    $.post('/MyApp/api/users/createUser',body)
    .done((data)=> console.log(data))
    .fail((err) => console.log(err))
},
```

Express

```
router.post('/users/createUser', async(req, res, next) => {
    console.log('/users/createUser'); 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)); 
    res.json(req.body); 
});
```

Console

```
// front end
index.vue ? 223 bf930 : 222
{
    user_id: 0
    , user_name: ""
    , user_email: ""
    , user_projects: Array(1)
}
user_email: ""
user_id: 0 user_name: ""
user_projects: Array(1) 0: {
    test: "test"
}
length: 1 __proto__: Array(0) __proto__: Object

// Express Response
index.vue ? 223 bf930 : 229 
{
    user_id: "0"
    , user_name: ""
    , user_email: ""
    , user_projects[0][test]: "test"
}
user_email: ""
user_id: "0"
user_name: ""
user_projects[0][test]: "test"
__proto__: Object
```

Solution, 
It was the way i was sending the data.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/MyApp/api/users/createUser',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(body)
    })
```

Comment: It's not a map. `user_projects` is an array. `user_projects[0]` is an object.

Comment: @Paulpro Well, technically everything is an object. But its an map object.\

Comment: No, it's really not. Why do you think that? There is nothing in your Express Response that indicates that.

Comment: The problem is that you are sending your data as a querystring but what  you need is json. Parsing querystring that holds an array will return an object instead of an array. All you need is to add a datatype to `$.post` so try this `$.post('/MyApp/api/users/createUser',body, 'json')`

Comment: @Molda, You are correct. Post an answer, ill make it correct.

Comment: Cool, i've posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending your data as a querystring but what you need is json. Parsing querystring that holds an array will return an object instead of an array.

All you need is to add a json datatype to `$.post`

So try this

```
$.post('/MyApp/api/users/createUser',body, 'json')
```

Comment: This is correct, but i had to use ajax to have express read it correctly.